# Calculate moment of a random variable via cdr

Tags: probability

I'm trying to prove the following: Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable then the following holds: $$\mathbb{E}[X^{p}]= \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X > t)pt^{p-1} dt$$

While my notes use Fubini-Tonelli theorem I don't understand why (and if) this solution is incorrect: $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X > t)pt^{p-1} dt= \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb(1-F(t))pt^{p-1} dt =|\mathbb{P}(X > t)t^{p}|_{0}^{\infty}+\int
_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X=t)t^{p} dt$$

where I'm using integration by part, the fact that $\mathbb{P}(X > \infty)=0$ and that $\mathbb{P}(X=t)$ is the derivative of the cdr.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Aside from the notational weirdness (you should write $f(t) = F'(t)$ for the derivative, rather than $P(X=t)$) it seems that the only thing missing is to justify why $P(X > t) t^p \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$. The fact that $P(X>t) \to 0$ is not sufficient (e.g., $P(X>t) = ct^{-(p-1)}$ would have $P(X>t) t^p \to \infty$.)

Comment: Yeah sure, it makes sense, mistake by me. If the random variable is integrable it follows from generalised Markov inequality, my motivation is clearly not sufficient. Thanks

Comment: I don't think the limit being zero actually follows from Markov's inequality: $\mathbb{P}(X>t) t^p=\mathbb{P}(X^p>t^p) t^p \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(X^p)}{t^p} t^p=\mathbb{E}(X^p)$, so it's just bounded, not necessarily going to zero. And you do need it to go to zero in order to make this argument with a (in general distributional) density work.

Comment: I wanted to use that for integrable random variable $$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \lambda P(|X|> \lambda)=0$$. But this seems to show the formula just for p=1.

Comment: No, that works if you assume the $p$th moment is finite. I'm just saying that that identity doesn't actually follow from Markov's inequality. Somehow what's happening is that as you send $a \to \infty$ in Markov's inequality, the bound eventually gets worse.

Comment: Ok, i think the misunderstanding is that we called the aforementioned equality "Strong Markov Inequality"